# Java duplicate entry and performance issue

Tags: java, database, performance, data-structures

Java + MySql

**What I have:**

I have a data class that stores (id, firstName, lastName, workingHours). I fetch this information from database and store in data class. This data class contains many duplicates, for example, each employee (with same first and last name) can work for different hours, for example,

```
peter nick 4
peter nick 2
peter nick 8
```

**What I am trying to do:**

I want to remove duplicate and store all the hours as an array or csv

For example

```
peter nick [4,2,8]
```

There are over 5 million records in database, I tried to use some database queries but it takes ages :(. I thought it would be fast if I load all data in memory and perform the task. I have 10GB RAM.

How can I accomplish this with best performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `GROUP BY id` and `GROUP_CONCAT`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: sounds awesome ! let me try this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve all rows sorted by firstname, lastname.  Then stream the rows into your Java application.  Open a file output stream to a csv file.  Start with the first record, and loop record by record.  While the firstname and lastname haven't changed, build up a list of working hours.  When the firstname and/or lastname changes, output to csv and start building a new list of working hours.

Comment: do you think its good from performance perspective? When there are millions records?